# Insert value into multiple columns using REGEXP_SUBSTR

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below query that is splitting up a comma separated value into multiple columns just how I want it to.

However, is there a way where I can insert the value into the columns for me to commit because right now the query is just selecting not inserting the value into the multiple columns.

Comment: Please share the table structure of the table you are trying to insert the information to (including all constraints) as well as some CSV data you are attempting to insert.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `VALUES` key word. Your insert statement should be

```sql
INSERT INTO table_1 (LINE1,LINE2,LOCATION,ID)
select 
case when instr(LINE1,',') >= 1
   then REGEXP_SUBSTR(LINE1, '[^,]+', 1, 1) 
   else null end LINE1,
case when instr(LINE1,',') >= 1
   then REGEXP_SUBSTR(LINE1, '[^,]+', 1, 2) 
   else LINE1 end LINE2,
case when instr(LINE1,',') >= 1
   then REGEXP_SUBSTR(LINE1, '[^,]+', 1, 3) 
   else null end LOCATION,
5 ID
from table_1
where ID ='5';
```

Comment: I removed the VALUES key word and now i am getting an error of: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("table_1"."ID")

Comment: @Richard You aren't inserting anything into the `ID` column and it is going to be `NULL`; if it has a non-null constraint then of course it is going to invalidate that constraint.

Comment: @MT0. right i see. and if i wanted to insert the value 5 in ID. how would i go about doing that because right now i have a where clause of 'where id = 5'

Comment: you could modify the columns being inserted to `(LINE1,LINE2,LOCATION,ID)` and add `5` as the 4th column of your select

Comment: @EJEgyed how would i add the 5 as the 4th column of my select? could you show me please.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the `VALUES` keyword (and from comments you need to include the `ID` column and value):

```sql
INSERT INTO table_1 (ID, LINE1, LINE2, LOCATION)
SELECT ID,
       CASE
       WHEN instr(LINE1,',') >= 1
       THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(LINE1, '[^,]+', 1, 1)
       END AS LINE1,
       CASE
       WHEN instr(LINE1,',') >= 1
       THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(LINE1, '[^,]+', 1, 2)
       ELSE LINE1
       END AS LINE2,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(LINE1, '[^,]+', 1, 3) AS LOCATION
FROM   table_1
WHERE  ID ='5';
```

Also, the `CASE` statements are redundant on the third occurrence as if you don't have a comma then there won't be a second or third occurrence and `REGEXP_SUBSTR` will return `NULL`.

Comment: for the second column (LINE2), `LINE1` is being returned in the `ELSE` condition of the `CASE` statement in OP's original select so this would change the results of that column.